# Logic App Service bus connector Get message from Queue(Peek-Lock) action return only single message from Queue even more than message in queue

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-servicebus-queues

I have been created two logic apps one for send message in queue and another one is for receive messages from queue

1. **Logic App Send Message :**  This Logic app fired on every 1 minute and insert message in queue

[image: Send Message Logic App workflow]
2. **Logic App Receive Message :**  This Logic app Fired after 20 min And i want to fetch all Messages send by send logic in one call

[image: Receive Messages from service bus Workflow]

**Problem :** In receive messages workflow i receive only 1 message per logic app trigger

Setting of Queue : 
[image: Setting of Queue]

Comment: Hi SahadevSing, we're looking into this issue.

Comment: Derek Li Thanks :)